# Disabling multiple button for multiple click issue in ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have 2  Buttons

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit1" Text="Submit"  runat="server"  OnClick="btnSubmit1_Click" OnClientClick="return Validation();" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit2" Text="Submit"  runat="server"  OnClick="btnSubmit2_Click" OnClientClick="return Validation();" />
```

On page load i am disabling those 2 if clicked (for multiple click issue)

```
btnsubmit1.OnClientClick = ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnsubmit1, "") + "; this.value='Processing...';this.disabled = true;";
btnsubmit2.OnClientClick = ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnSubmit2, "") + "; this.value='Processing...';this.disabled = true;";
```

Now i want to disable both buttons even if i have clicked one button. how do i  achieve this?

Comment: What you are trying to do exactly?

Comment: I want to disable both buttons in client side, even if one button is clicked. Then it has to go to CODE BEHIND.

Answer (score 0):

Client Side:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function disableButtons() {
 var btn1 = document.getElementById("<%=btnSubmit1.ClientID%>");
 var btn2 = document.getElementByID("<%=btnSubmit2.ClientID%>");
 btn1.disabled = true; btn2.disable = true;
}
</script>
```

Server Side: on Page Load

```
btnsubmit1.OnClientClick = "disableButtons();this.value='Processing...'"
btnsubmit1.OnClientClick = "disableButtons();this.value='Processing...'"
```

I notice you have also mentioned another function "return validation()" in mark ups. if you are using asp.net webforms validations. I think whatever the scripts required for validations get added automatically after your custom scripts in the rendered html.